# How can I remove duplicates from a list of dataclass-objects which each have a list as a field?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have this code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List

@dataclass(eq=True, frozen=True)
class TestClass:
    field1: str
    field_list: List[str]

duplicate_list = [TestClass("foo", ["bar", "cat"]), TestClass("foo", ["bar", "cat"]), TestClass("foo", ["bar", "caz"])]

unique_list = remove_duplicates(duplicate_list)

def remove_duplicates(duplicate_list: List[TestClass]) -> List[TestClass]:
    return list(set(duplicate_list))
```

Now I want to check the list for duplicates. I tried to convert the list to a set like shown above. I also tried using

```
return list( dict.fromkeys(duplicate_list) )
```

Both approaches do not work as my class contains a list. Because of this the `__hash__` function generated by the dataclass module does not work. It gives the error: `unhashable type: 'list'`

What would the correct approach be to remove the duplicate dataclass-elements? Would I need to write a custom `__hash__` function? Or would it be possible to replace the list with some form of immutable list?

Comment: To answer your last q: either works.  Which is right depends on context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `list` with `tuple` (immutable list in python)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import List, Tuple


@dataclass(eq=True, frozen=True)
class TestClass:
    field1: str
    field_list: Tuple[str, str]


duplicate_list = [TestClass("foo", ("bar", "cat")), TestClass("foo", ("bar", "cat")), TestClass("foo", ("bar", "caz"))]
```

Then your original `remove_duplicates` implementation will work correctly.

```
def remove_duplicates(duplicate_list: List[TestClass]) -> List[TestClass]:
    return list(set(duplicate_list))
```

Comment: As I have "immutable lists" with different lengths I used  `Tuple[str, ...]` instead of `Tuple[str, str]`

Answer (score 0):

Just change duplicate_list with:

```
duplicate_list = [TestClass("foo", ["bar", "cat"]).__str__(), TestClass("foo", ["bar", "cat"]).__str__(), TestClass("foo", ["bar", "cat"]).__str__()]
```